Binomial coefficients of noncommuting objects $a$ and $b$ satisfying $ba=1$.
Consider the expansion of $(a+b)^n$ wherein $a$ and $b$ do not commute and $ba=1$. What is the expansion coefficient of the term $a^k$, for $k<n$?

Have you tried it for several small $n$?

Catalan numbers are relevant.

Assuming $ba=1$ is the only nontrivial algebraic operation possible, one can solve the problem by defining the symmetric polynomials
$$Q_n(a,b)=\sum_{k=0}^na^k b^{n-k}$$
It is easy to show that these polynomials play well with multiplication (left or right) by $Q_1=a+b$; indeed
$$(a+b)Q_n(a,b)=Q_{n+1}(a,b)+Q_{n-1}(a,b)$$
Using this recursion we write down the first few non-trivial powers of $Q_1$:
$$(a+b)^2=Q_0+Q_2$$
$$(a+b)^3=2Q_1+Q_3$$
$$(a+b)^4=2Q_0+3Q_2+Q_4~~ ...$$
We note that the coefficients of the expansion $(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n C_{nk} Q_k$, due to the Pascal type recursion, follows the structure of A053121, a Catalan triangle with zeroes:
$$\begin{matrix}
    1\\
    0&1\\
    1&0&1\\
    0&2&0&1\\
    2&0&3&0&1\\
    0&5&0&4&0&1\\
    5&0&9&0&5&0&1\\
    \dots\\
\end{matrix}$$
These coefficients were thoroughly studied in this post and an explicit formula is available. As it turns out, the binomial expansion for this set of noncommuting variables can be written as
$$(a+b)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}D^{(n)}_{k}Q_{n-2k}$$
$$D^{(n)}_k={n\choose k}-{n\choose k-1}=\frac{n-2k+1}{n-k+1}{n\choose k}$$
